# Dataflow job stuck at reading from Pub/Sub

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

Our SDK version is `Apache Beam Python 3.7 SDK 2.25.0`

There is a pipeline which reads data from Pub/Sub, transforms it and saves results to GCS.
Usually it works fine for 1-2 weeks. After that it stucks.

```
"Operation ongoing in step s01 for at least 05m00s without outputting or completing in state process
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
  at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.fn.data.RemoteGrpcPortWriteOperation.maybeWait(RemoteGrpcPortWriteOperation.java:175)
  at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.fn.data.RemoteGrpcPortWriteOperation.process(RemoteGrpcPortWriteOperation.java:196)
  at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
  at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:201)
  at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159)
  at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77)
  at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.fn.control.BeamFnMapTaskExecutor.execute(BeamFnMapTaskExecutor.java:123)
  at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1400)
  at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1100(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:156)
  at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$7.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1101)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Step 01 is just a `"Read PubSub Messages" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=subscription)`

After this dataflow increases the number of workers and stops processing any new data. Job is still in `RUNNNING` state.

We just need to restart the job to solve it. But it happens every ~2 weeks.

How can we fix it?

Comment: Hard to know. It's like a deadlock. The support can help..

Comment: I think we need a lot more information to debug this. Are you able to file a support ticket? And if not, can you provide more information about your pipeline?

Comment: @Artyom Tokachev, you can report this error on issue [tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers), whilst sharing the pipeline details.

Comment: @Artyom Tokachev did you manage to solve your issue? Any suggestion for people with a similar situation?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with the legacy "Java Runner Harness."  I would suggest running your pipeline with [Dataflow Runner v2](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#dataflow-runner-v2) to avoid these kinds of issues. You could also wait until it becomes the default (it is currently rolling out).